# JPA @Query how to use count, distinct & concat together version

Tags: spring-data-jpa

JPA version 1.11.22

Inside a `@Query` how can we use `count`, `distinct` & `concat` together.
Basically I want the distinct count of a group of multiple columns.

I've tried the following queries

`@Query("SELECT count(distinct concat(col1, col2, col3)) from entity where col1 is not null")`

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an exemple of the query?

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss I used the following query and it is not compiling
@Query("SELECT count(distinct concat(col1, col2, col3)) from entity where col1 is not null")

Answer (score 1):

I tried with work around for this and it worked.
Try to add this to your entity @Formula (from org.hibernate.annotations) like below,

@Formula("concat(col1, col2, col3)")
private String concated;

and in spring repository, try with
@Query("SELECT count(distinct concated) from entity where col1 is not null")